# Save changes on VS code

Tags: visual-studio-code, autosave

I have made changes on a HTML and js file on VS code and then I opened the same folder that contains the same files on another window and seems like no changes where applied to it. I have autosave on. Is there a way to make it work.

this is the change I made to it. adding the `addedButton` function will not appear once ht file is reopend

```
buttonNew[0].addEventListener('click', () => {
    formD[0].style.display = 'block'
    shownId.display = 'none'
    console.log('cliced')

})

addedButton[0].addEventListener('click', () => {
  if(shownId.innerHTML !== null){
    formD[0].style.display = 'none'
  }
})
```

[image]
If I reopen either from another window on VS code or directly by clicking on the file form the folder changes will not be

Comment: what happens when you manually save? If reflects?

Comment: *it seems like to changes where applied to it* -- Why do say "seems like"?  You can open the file and see for yourself.  It either is, or it isn't.

Comment: @MuhammadSaqlain yes, I even tried replacing it but still doesn't change